# docker build and publish plugin usage

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins

I have jenkins running as Docker container, I tried to install jenkins build and publish plugin here and copied Dockerfile inside jenkins workspace, but whenever I run the build, it gives me:

```
Started by user Jenkins Admin
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace
[workspace] $ docker build -t index.docker.io/test/openshift:latest --pull=true /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test/workspace
ERROR: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:803)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)

Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

could you please tell me why is that so?

Answer (score 6):

Inside a Docker container you have no access to the `docker`-binary by default (hence the error message `No such file or directory`).

If you want to use Docker within a Docker container, you need to either use **DinD** (Docker-in-Docker) or **DooD** (Docker-outside-of-Docker).
The first is a separate Docker installation within your Jenkins-container, the second only mounts the hosts Docker installation via volumes.

Further reading about **DinD** in general and in regards to Jenkins:

- https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/
- https://github.com/killercentury/docker-jenkins-dind
- https://github.com/tehranian/dind-jenkins-slave

Further reading about **DooD** in general and in regards to Jenkins:

- http://container-solutions.com/running-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/axltxl/jenkins-dood/

---

### Update

The information on using the Workflow plugin below is no longer correct.
I have since written a plugin called [`docker-swarm-slave`](https://github.com/pitkley/docker-swarm-slave) that offers a build-wrapper you can configure for a job which automatically provisions a Docker-container for a build, if you use my [`jenkins-dood`-image](https://hub.docker.com/r/pitkley/jenkins-dood/) or are running directly on bare metal.

Documentation unfortunately is rather sparse, but maybe it is useful to somebody.

---

I have a similar use-case: I want to be able to automatically start a Docker-container with a specified image running a  [Jenkins Swarm client](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Swarm+Plugin) that will take over the build.
My [`jenkins-dood`-image](https://hub.docker.com/r/pitkley/jenkins-dood/) contains a script [`docker-slave`](https://github.com/pitkley/dockerfiles/blob/master/jenkins-dood/1.625.3/docker-slave) which lets me automatically provision a Docker-Swarm-slave and execute what I need on it using the [Workflow-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin) with a script like the following:

```
node('master') {
    stage 'Create docker-slave'
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'swarm-login', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
        sh 'docker-slave --job-name $JOB_NAME --build-number $BUILD_NUMBER -i pitkley/python-swarm:3.4 -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD -- -labels "${JOB_NAME}_${BUILD_NUMBER}"'
    }

    stage 'Execute on docker-slave'
    node("${env.JOB_NAME}_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}") {
        sh 'hostname'
    }

    stage 'Remove docker-slave'
    sh 'docker-slave --job-name $JOB_NAME --build-number $BUILD_NUMBER --rm'
}
```

(This assumes you need credentials to authenticate which are saved with a short-ID of `swarm-credentials`.)